# Convert symbol to HTML entity

Tags: python, character

I have a Python script ([source here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8510b2919270ee81bea4)) to convert symbols to HTML entities (it will be used in a scraper).

**When I run this script, it spits me back out the copyright symbol. Others run this and it works as expected. I may have mis-tagged it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `str` representations. The script works perfectly fine with Python 3 since `str` is the `unicode` type. In Python 2 `str` is comparable to the new `bytes` type and © in its UTF-8 representation is a two byte character.

So better use `unicode` everywhere, just like `u"©"` and `a.decode('utf-8')`.